# Proper way to terminate object creation inside of __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best approach to doing this. I have a class that does some sanity checking on the passed arguments, if something fails a check, I want to fail creating the object so that I can test for this in the calling segment.

Example:

```
class DoSomething(object):

    def __init__(self, _x, _y, _z)
        if _x < 0:
            return None
        #snip

    @property
    def x(self):
        return x

a = DoSomething(-1, 1, 2)

if not a:
    print "error"
else:
    print a.x
```

When run, a is still a 'valid' object and so "print a.x" gets executed and throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./c.1", line 19, in <module>
    print a.x
  File "./c.1", line 11, in x
    return x
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

I was wanting to avoid defining and raising my own exceptions. Is there any way I can do this w/o doing that?

Thx!

Comment: why do you want to avoid exceptions?

Comment: I just wanna keep this simple and concise. It's just a simple tool I'm  writing.

Comment: Handling exceptions is much easier than complex if-else blocks IMO.

Comment: you cannot return in the init method

Comment: @BenH exceptions are simple and concise. You're going to end up with some hidden behavior that is not good practice

Comment: Yea I guess I'll put in my own exceptions, gonna need that in my next tool anyways. Thx for the suggestions.

Comment: You don't need your own exception; a `ValueError` describes an argument of the correct type but unacceptable value perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `__new__` for this purpose:

```
class DoSomething(object):
    def __new__(cls, _x, _y, _z):
        if _x < 0:
            return None
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

You can't stop the creation of an object in `__init__` because the object is already there (that's the `self` argument).

Example of the above:

```
>>> DoSomething(1, 2, 3)
<__main__.DoSomething object at 0x108b57e48>
>>> DoSomething(-1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

That being said, it's more common to raise an exception from `__init__` and try/except around it:

```
try:
    obj = DoSomething(-1, 2, 3)
except MyException:
    pass
```

This is more intuitive to other developers (as effectively you're saying: it's not possible to initialise the object with that negative value for `_x`). It also avoids lesser-known features of Python (`__new__`) and the exceptions can be handled cleanly.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it answered my post but I think I will go the custom exception route now. Thx everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use exceptions. A ValueError would fit perfectly:

```
class DoSomething(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z)
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError('x is negative')
        # snip
        self.x = x

try:
    a = DoSomething(-1, 1, 2)
except ValueError:
    print "error"
else:
    print a.x
```

By the way, if a variable starts with a `_` it's convention, that this variable is not needed and is only there to fulfill a interface restriction; only attributes starting with `_` mean «not belonging to the public interface». A property is not necessary here.